# SWT windows hierachy and global data

Tags: java, internationalization, swt, preferences, applicationwindow

After a few time enjoying the help of this site, the time to integrate myself here has come!

Well, I'm starting a personal project using java (under Windows 7), and I'm getting started with SWT. After a search of hours, I'm not satisfied with the short information I reached.

The project is an application where I will have a main window, from where the user can access to different modules (Customers Management, products management...).

What I want is to set properly:

A) I18n languagues
B) User preferences

"Properly" means a good,proper and easy access from all the components of the program to that data to use it, having in mind to do it through the most "standardized" way too.

I already created a package called "LanguagueResources", where I have the MessageBundle_xx_XX.properties, and I defined the following attributes on my MainMenu Class

```
protected String languague="en";
protected String country="UK";
protected Locale currentLocale=new Locale(languague, country);
protected ResourceBundle 
messages=ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessageBundle",currentLocale);
```

With this, my main menu works fine with the different languagues. But what happens when I open a new window? maybe I can declare it this again (too much repeated code), or maybe I can pass some data when I call the new window instance (this doesn't look stylish). Same with other possible preferences settings.

This also makes me wonder how I must construct the program structre.I mean, is correct to start with a SWT Application window (Main Menu), and from there, call other SWT Application windows which will be the different modules (Customers, products)? Maybe must I establish an independent Main class where I will call MainMenu class, and where I will define the languague resources and preferences resources?

Also, I would like to know if the user preferences must be saved like the languages (.properties file)

I think I can do it trough many ways, but I would like to know which is the recommended,standarized and easiest way to do it.

I hope I explained well.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just create a `class` having all those things `static`, i.e. the settings are `static` and just create a `static` method that returns the i18n string. That way you can access your resources from everywhere.

Comment: It's an option. I decided to use it for I18N. Regarding to user preferences, I' m taking a look to Java Preferences API (java.util.prefs.Preferences). It seems to be more appropiated than using a generic custom class made by myself. Thanks for the answer.